# google closure compiler's advanced optimization isn't optimizing some variables

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm running into an issue with the Google Closure Javascript compiler with advanced optimization. As the documentation suggests, to preserve exported Javascript I do something like this:

```
var myClass = function() {
   this["myFunc"] = this.myFunc;
   this["myFunc2"] = this.myFunc2;
};
window["myClass"] = myClass;

myClass.prototype = {
    myFunc: function() { alert("myFunc"); },
    myFunc2: function() { alert("myFunc2"); }
};
```

The issue is that sometimes, for whatever reason, `myFunc` and `myFunc2` don't get shortened, and I see code like this in the final output:

```
x.myFunc=x.myFunc;x.myFunc2=x.myFunc2;
```

This is obviously less than ideal.

How can I prevent this from happening?

---

Further experimentation has shown that there are certain keywords, e.g. 'get' that don't get compiled.

```
var myClass = function() {
   this["get"] = this.get;
   this["myFunc2"] = this.myFunc2;
};
window["myClass"] = myClass;

myClass.prototype = {
    get: function() { alert("myFunc"); },
    myFunc2: function() { alert("myFunc2"); }
};
```

Compiles into

```
function a() {
  this.get = this.get;
  this.myFunc2 = this.a
}
window.myClass = a;
a.prototype = {get:function() {
  alert("myFunc")
}, a:function() {
  alert("myFunc2")
}};
```

I still don't know what's causing it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot duplicate your problem. If I go to http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home and compile the following:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

var myClass = function() {
  this["myFunc"] = this.myFunc;
  this["myFunc2"] = this.myFunc2;
};
window["myClass"] = myClass;

myClass.prototype = {
  myFunc: function() { alert("myFunc"); },
  myFunc2: function() { alert("myFunc2"); }
};
```

Then I get the following result:

```
function a(){this.myFunc=this.a;this.myFunc2=this.b}window.myClass=a;a.prototype={a:function(){alert("myFunc")},b:function(){alert("myFunc2")}};
```

The properties are renamed, as expected.

As for your second example, it has to do with a Closure Compiler concept known as [externs](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#externs). An *extern* is a symbol that will be predefined in the environment in which the JavaScript will run, such as `window` or `document` in the case of Web programming. Because such names are fixed in the environment, the Compiler cannot mangle these names.

If you look at the `DEFAULT_EXTERNS_NAMES` list in [CommandLineRunner.java](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner.java), you will see a list of files from the [externs](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/#trunk%2Fexterns) folder. The contents of these files define the externs that the Compiler knows about (you can also add your own externs). Both `webgl.js` and `w3c_indexeddb.js` define types with a property named `get` (`WebGLContextAttributes` and `IDBObjectStore`, respectively). By default, the Compiler does not know the type of `this` in `myClass`, so as far as it knows, `this` could refer to an instance of either `WebGLContextAttributes` or `IDBObjectStore`, in which case it would not be safe to rename `get`.

By using a combination of type annotations (such as `@constructor`) and Compiler options such as `ambiguateProperties` and `disambiguateProperties`, the Compiler can determine that `this` will always refer to a new instance of `myClass` and rename all of its references to `get` consistently. You can read more about these Compiler optimizations in Chapter 14 of *Closure: The Definitive Guide*.

Comment: Which annotations in particular should I use?

Comment: And how can I set ambiguate/disambiguate via the command line interface?

Comment: You need to use annotations that contain type information: @constructor, @extends, @param, and @return.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot set ambiguate/disambiguate from the command line interface. Your options are either to (1) use plovr (which I recommend, but I'm biased!), or (2) to use the Compiler programmatically and write Java code to enable those passes.

Answer (score 1):

From the [example here](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#removal), it looks like you need to explicitly export prototype methods outside of the constructor:

```
var myClass = function() {};
myClass.prototype = {
    myFunc: function() { alert("myFunc"); },
    myFunc2: function() { alert("myFunc2"); }
};

window["myClass"] = myClass;
myClass.prototype["myFunc"] = myClass.prototype.myFunc;
myClass.prototype["myFunc2"] = myClass.prototype.myFunc2;
```

This seems to work as advertised, though it seems like an odd optimization to me (all the repeated "prototype" references add a lot of bytes):

```
function a(){}a.prototype={a:function(){alert("myFunc")},
b:function(){alert("myFunc2")}};
window.myClass=a;
a.prototype.myFunc=a.prototype.a;
a.prototype.myFunc2=a.prototype.b;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, the GCC treats myObject["a"] differently from myObject.a.  Try the following:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.attr1 = 3;
myObject["attr2"] = 4;
window["myObject"] = myObject;
```

It will compile to this, with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS:

```
window.myObject={a:3,attr2:4};
```

I think you'll see what you need to do now.

Comment: No. I understand that, which is why I am doing the `this["xyz"] = this.xyz`. That is similar to the `window["myObject"] = myObject`, unless I'm missing something.